# When do we need to implement a custom TypeConverter in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I've been reading about TypeConverter in MVC. [This article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) talks about how to implement. It briefly says when it is necessary to write our own type converter:

> Most native data types (Int32, String, enumeration types, and others)
>   have default type converters that provide string-to-value conversions
>   and perform validation checks. The default type converters are in the
>   System.ComponentModel namespace and are named
>   TypeConverterNameConverter. **You can extend a type converter when the
>   default functionality is not adequate for your purposes or implement a
>   custom type converter when you define a custom type that does not have
>   an associated type converter**.

But, when does the situation (in bold in the quote) happen? I never needed to write custom type converter for my Student, Employee, Teacher classes in my mvc projects, and they work just fine. So, obviously, I am missing something. Could you give me a real example that would **require** a custom type converter to be implemented or is best solved by a custom type converter? Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: The article you linked has an example right in it. It can't out, out of the box, convert points.

Comment: Yes, I've taken a look at that example, but why it can't convert out of the box a point? In other words, why I don't need to write a custom TypeConverter for my Student, Teacher, Course classes?

Comment: I'd have to see what you're code looks like, but I'm guessing it's because you're not actually converting those types, but rather native types within them (e.g. student.Age where Age is an int).

Comment: I am not trying to implement anything at this moment, it's my thinking during reading. If I use strongly typed views, I let the default model binder take care of the bindings. In other words, I don't worry about type conversion myself even if I have custom classes in my projects such as Student, Course, Teacher which obviously don't exist in the .NET framework. Even in the example given in the MSDN article, a Point is defined as Point(int, int), a type comprised of native type int.

Answer (score 1):

One of my projects required a serve time to be passed as either a regular time (7:15 PM) or a sports period (Inning 3), so I had to implement a `struct ServeTime` to handle the dualism, and also `ServeTimeConverter` to bind to the model.